# go to another page with POST via a

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

I have a page base.html where i go at index.php with a link:

```
<a id="goTo" href="#">go to...</a>
```

So, i need to send at index.php a POST message like param='myValue' using the jQuery library. I have try use this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#goTo').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        alert('Ok!');
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            data: 'param=MyValue'
            url: 'index.php',
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

But does not work as i want. How i can do?

**Edit**
I need to go into index.php and not remain in base.html .

Comment: How you want it to work?

Comment: I need only obtain in the index.php capture the POST message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this for the data?

```
data: { param: "MyValue" },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#goTo').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        alert('Ok!');
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            data: { param: "MyValue"},
            url: 'index.php',
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to actually take the user to index.php:

You could have a form with appropriate action and method:

```
<form id="theForm" action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="param" value="MyValue" />
</form>
```

And then submit the form:

```
$('#goTo').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#theForm').submit();
});
```

---

Or you could put a button in the form and let the html do the work for you:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="param" value="MyValue" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Ok, i have try this and work fine, but it's possible to do that with <a> ?

Comment: Yes, see the first example in my answer.

Comment: @dceccon your requirements look like some kind of workaround :-) If you want to submit some post data into server and redirect a user to next page - you should use form with submit button (easiest solution, html standards). <a> should be used for linking hrefs, why you want to submit a form using <a>?

Comment: for integrate in a pre-exist web page...
but i think i do with form ;)